# How to globally force Laravel to only send plain-text emails?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Is there a way to make all built-in emails in a Laravel app only be plain-text?

I mean the emails added to the `views/vendor/mail` folder after running `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail`.

I'm hopping this can be done via config but it doesn't look like it's possible.

Comment: As far as I know, you can define your theme. But the plain text, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to define a plain-text version of your email, you may use the text method.

```
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.orders.shipped')
                ->text('emails.orders.shipped_plain');
}
```

Check [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I want to avoid is to change all those built in emails one by one.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to export all laravel built-in emails by running:

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail`

And then editing `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/layout.blade.php` to remove all header/footer and other unwanted HTML.